# Implement hash table using linear congruential probing in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, object-oriented, hash-map

I have just read the Chapter 5 of [Data Structures and Algorithms with Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00S5XEY2E). The authors implemented hash sets using linear probing. However, linear probing may result in lots of clustering. So I decided to implement my hash table with a similar approach but using [linear **congruential** probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) instead.

Below is my code:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping


def _probe_seq(key, list_len):
    """
    Generate the probing sequence of the key by the linear congruential generator:
        x = (5 * x + c) % list_len
    In order for the sequence to be a permutation of range(m),
    list_len must be a power of 2 and c must be odd.
    We choose to compute c by hashing str(key) prefixed with underscore and
        c = (2 * hashed_string - 1) % list_len
    so that c is always odd.
    This way two colliding keys would likely (but not always) have different probing sequences.
    """
    x = hash(key) % list_len
    yield x

    hashed_string = hash('_' + str(key))
    c = (2 * hashed_string - 1) % list_len

    for _ in range(list_len - 1):
        x = (5 * x + c) % list_len
        yield x


class HashTable(MutableMapping):
    """A hash table using linear congruential probing as the collision resolution.
    Under the hood we use a private list self._items to store the items.
    We rehash the items to a larger list (resp. smaller list) every time the original list
    becomes too crowded (resp. too sparse).
    For probing to work properly, len(self._items) must always be a power of 2.
    """
    # _init_size must be a power of 2 and not too large, 8 is reasonable
    _init_size = 8

    # a placeholder for any deleted item
    _placeholder = object()

    def __init__(self, items=None):
        """
        :argument:
        items (iterable of tuples): an iterable of (key, value) pairs
        """
        self._items = [None] * HashTable._init_size
        self._len = 0

        if items is not None:
            for key, value in items:
                self[key] = value

    def __len__(self):
        """Return the number of items."""
        return self._len

    def __iter__(self):
        """Iterate over the keys."""
        for item in self._items:
            if item not in (None, HashTable._placeholder):
                yield item[0]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """Get the value corresponding to the key.
        Raise KeyError if no such key found
        """
        probe = _probe_seq(key, len(self._items))
        idx = next(probe)

        # return the value if key found while probing self._items
        while self._items[idx] is not None:
            if (self._items[idx] is not HashTable._placeholder
                    and self._items[idx][0] == key):
                return self._items[idx][1]
            idx = next(probe)

        raise KeyError

    @staticmethod
    def _add(key, value, items):
        """Helper function for __setitem__ to probe the items list.
        Return False if found the key and True otherwise.
        In either cases, set the value at the correct location.
        """
        loc = None
        probe = _probe_seq(key, len(items))
        idx = next(probe)

        while items[idx] is not None:
            # key found, set value at the same location
            if items[idx] is not HashTable._placeholder and items[idx][0] == key:
                items[idx] = (key, value)
                return False

            # remember the location of the first placeholder found during probing
            if loc is None and items[idx] is HashTable._placeholder:
                loc = idx

            idx = next(probe)

        # key not found, set the item at the location of the first placeholder
        # or at the location of None at the end of the probing sequence
        if loc is None:
            loc = idx
        items[loc] = (key, value)

        return True

    @staticmethod
    def _rehash(old_list, new_list):
        """Rehash the items from old_list to new_list"""
        for item in old_list:
            if item not in (None, HashTable._placeholder):
                HashTable._add(*item, new_list)

        return new_list

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        """Set self[key] to be value.
        Overwrite the old value if key found.
        """
        if HashTable._add(key, value, self._items):
            self._len += 1
            if self._len / len(self._items) > 0.75:
                # too crowded, rehash to a larger list
                # resizing factor is 2 so that the length remains a power of 2
                new_list = [None] * (len(self._items) * 2)
                self._items = HashTable._rehash(self._items, new_list)

    @staticmethod
    def _remove(key, items):
        """Helper function for __delitem__ to probe the items list.
        Return False if key not found.
        Otherwise, delete the item and return True.
        (Note that this is opposite to _add because
        for _add, returning True means an item has been added, while
        for _remove, returning True means an item has been removed.)
        """
        probe = _probe_seq(key, len(items))
        idx = next(probe)

        while items[idx] is not None:
            next_idx = next(probe)

            # key found, replace the item with the placeholder
            if items[idx] is not HashTable._placeholder and items[idx][0] == key:
                items[idx] = HashTable._placeholder
                return True

            idx = next_idx

        return False

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        """Delete self[key].
        Raise KeyError if no such key found.
        """
        # key found, remove one item
        if HashTable._remove(key, self._items):
            self._len -= 1
            numerator = max(self._len, HashTable._init_size)

            if numerator / len(self._items) < 0.25:
                # too sparse, rehash to a smaller list
                # resizing factor is 1/2 so that the length remains a power of 2
                new_list = [None] * (len(self._items) // 2)
                self._items = HashTable._rehash(self._items, new_list)

        else:
            raise KeyError
```

I would like same feedbacks to improve my code. Thank you.

**Reference:**

Data Structures and Algorithms with Python, Kent D. Lee and Steve Hubbard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tests

Given something this low-level, as well as your claims that it solves specific clustering problems - you need to test it. The tests for something like this, thankfully, are relatively easy. You may also want to do some rough profiling to get an idea of how this scales in comparison to the built-in hash method.

### Type hints

```
def __init__(self, items=None):
```

can probably be

```
HashableItems = Iterable[
    Tuple[Hashable, Any]
]
# ...

def __init__(self, items: Optional[HashableItems]=None):
```

### Class method

`_rehash` and `_remove` should be `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod` because they reference `HashTable`, which can be replaced with `cls`.